# Is it possible to not have a password with OWIN web api 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm starting to mess with the new Web API 2 template that uses OWIN/OAUTH2.

I want to setup a database table that stores an API key as opposed to a username/password that's passed in when generating a token.

Is this possible with OWIN?

Comment: This may help you: http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom grant_type which allows me to pass in whatever params I wanted.